# applying css transition on button after click (active: property)

Tags: html, css

I have my button where after clicking i am giving it a box-shadow just say in the active property like

```
.thankyou_button_active {
  background-color: #ff9d72;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff9d72;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  height: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: transform  1s all;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.thankyou_button_active:active {
  transition: transform  1s all;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #ff9d72;
}
```

so in the 'active' property i tried to apply transition property but it doesnt work out...does transtion in

> class:active

works in a different manner ??

Answer (score 0):

`transition: transform  1s all` is not a legit shorthand value, see [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) for more information.

You need to put `transition` to main class(in this case, `.thankyou_button_active`), and put the changed properties to property selector class: `.thankyou_button_active:active`. Unless you want to set the duration separately, check this for example:

```css
.thankyou_button_active {
  background-color: #ff9d72;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff9d72;
  width: 120px;
  outline: none;
  height: 31px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-shadow:0 0 0px #ff9d72;
}

.thankyou_button_active:active {
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #ff9d72;
  transition-duration: 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<button class="thankyou_button_active">Thank You</button>
```